# Predicate to filter array of strings in SWIFT throws error saying NSCFString is not key-value coding

Tags: arrays, swift, nsarray, nspredicate

Below is my code snippet

```
//Search Bar Delegate
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    println(searchText)
    var predicate:NSPredicate=NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] \(searchText)")!
    self.listItemToBeDisplayed=listItem.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
    (self.view.viewWithTag(1) as UITableView).reloadData()

}
```

Error I got:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x17405ef90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key V.'

I want to filter strings in array to be filtered by my search string. If my search string is contained in any of the string in array, then it should be listed.

Comment: sorry, code formatting is not working.

Comment: thanks nhgrif for formatting the code, really appreciate it. safari going crazy these days.

Comment: I believe `NSPredicate(format:)`strongly expects to be used with `printf`-style format strings (it automatically quotes arguments as it inserts them, etc). You're using Swift's string interpolation—that might be the problem.

Comment: awesome! fixed it. Now its not crashing. var predicate:NSPredicate=NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS %@", searchText)!  how to mark this question answered?

Comment: Now you can. That was sort of a guess, so I didn't put it in an answer right away. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NSPredicate(format:)` strongly expects to be used with printf-style format strings (it automatically quotes arguments as it inserts them, etc).

You're using Swift's string interpolation, so the already-formatted query comes to `NSPredicate` as a single string. That keeps it from doing whatever voodoo it does with arguments, leaving you with a malformed query.

Use printf-style formatting instead:

```
if let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS %@", searchText) {
    self.listItemToBeDisplayed = (listItem as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
    (self.view.viewWithTag(1) as UITableView).reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Sure it does — but it's provided by `NSArray`, not `Swift.Array`, and since Swift 1.2 you have to manually cast to make use of `NSArray` API. Updated answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Working with predicate for pretty long time. Here is my conclusion (SWIFT)

```
//Customizable! (for me was just important if at least one)
request.fetchLimit = 1


//IF IS EQUAL

//1 OBJECT
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", txtFieldName.text)

//ARRAY
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@ AND nickName = %@", argumentArray: [name, nickname])


// IF CONTAINS

//1 OBJECT
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", txtFieldName.text)

//ARRAY
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@ AND nickName contains[c] %@", argumentArray: [name, nickname])
```