# Cannot convert value of type '[Record]' to type 'Record' in coercion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

Im re-writing an iOS app I made using C# and Xamarin to Swift for obvious reasons of Xamarin's pricing, and low documentation. Following [this tutorial](https://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/6/27/uisearchcontroller-in-swift-xcode-7-ios-9-tutorial) for including a `UISearchBar` on my `UITableView`, i ran into this error: `Cannot convert value of type '[Record]' to type 'Record' in coercion`. Record.swift is a struct file I created to store the data that I will retrieve using cloudkit, but Im not sure how this error comes to be.

Here is the problem part of MasterViewController.swift:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filteredRecords.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS [c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    // Here is where the error shows
    let array = (self.records as Record).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredRecords = array as! [Record]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Heres the full MasterViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
    var records = [Record]()
    var filteredRecords = [Record]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "insertNewObject:")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }

        // #REMOVE - Testing implementation until iCloud is setup
        self.records = [
            Record(album: "The Awakening", artist: "P.O.D.",  genre: "Hardcore Rock", year: 2015, speed: "33 1/3", size: 12),
            Record(album: "Attack of The Killer B-Sides", artist: "A Day to Remember",  genre: "Post-Hardcore", year: 2010, speed: "33 1/3", size: 7),
            Record(album: "All I Want", artist: "A Day to Remember",  genre: "Post-Hardcore", year: 2011, speed: "33 1/3", size: 7),
            Record(album: "The White Stripes", artist: "The White Stripes",  genre: "Rock", year: 2003, speed: "45", size: 7),
            Record(album: "Save Rock and Roll", artist: "Fall Out Boy",  genre: "Punk Rock", year: 2013, speed: "33 1/3", size: 10),
            Record(album: "A Perfect Sky", artist: "Yellowcard",  genre: "Pop-Punk", year: 2015, speed: "33 1/3", size: 10),
            Record(album: "Noise vs Beauty", artist: "Bassnectar",  genre: "Dubstep", year: 2014, speed: "33 1/3", size: 12)
        ]

        // Configure the search bar controller
        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

        // Reload the data upon startup
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController!.collapsed
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

//    func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
//        objects.insert(NSDate(), atIndex: 0)
//        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
//        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
//    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let object = records[indexPath.row]
                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
            return self.filteredRecords.count
        } else {
            return self.records.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
            let object = filteredRecords[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel!.text = object.album
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = object.artist
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        } else {
            let object = records[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel!.text = object.album
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = object.artist
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            records.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filteredRecords.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS [c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (self.records as Record).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        self.filteredRecords = array as! [Record]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And Record.swift:

```
import Foundation

struct Record {
    let album : String
    let artist : String
    let genre : String
    let year : Int
    let speed : String
    let size : Int
}
```

Hopefully it will be a simple fix. if not, are there any tutorial suggestions? or other places I should ask this instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filteredArrayUsingPredicate` is an NSArray method, so you should cast it to NSArray:

```
let array = (self.records as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

But this still generate an error "[Record] is not convertible to NSArray". This is because an NSArray can only contain Objective-C objects, and Record is a Swift struct and is not convertible to an object. There are two solutions.

Solution 1:

Declare Record as an object

```
class Record: NSObject {
    let album : String
    let artist : String
    let genre : String
    let year : Int
    let speed : String
    let size : Int

    init(album : String, artist : String, genre : String, year : Int, speed : String, size : Int) {
        self.album = album
        self.artist = artist
        self.genre = genre
        self.year = year
        self.speed = speed
        self.size = size
    }
}
```

Then the following code should works

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.artist CONTAINS [c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
let array = (self.records as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
self.filteredRecords = array as! [Record]
```

Note your original predicate doesn't make sense, and would cause runtime error,  because Record is not a String, so I replace it.

Solution 2:

Use the Swift way to filter:

```
let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
filteredRecords = self.records.filter { (aRecord) -> Bool in
    return aRecord.artist.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText)
}
```

Comment: How could I get Solution 2 to search through the album and artist?

Comment: return aRecord.artist.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText) || aRecord.album.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText)

Comment: Ah the simplicity. Thanks, I'll try that in the morning.

Comment: The solution 2 is essentially the same as Dharmesh Kheni's edited answer

Comment: Thank you so much! This was stumping me all night.

Answer (score 2):

Because I think type of your `self.records` is `[Record]` and you are trying to casting it as single `Record` which is not an `Array`.  So it is not possible.

Try this:

```
let array = (self.records as [Record]).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

**UPDATE:**

Update your `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` method like this:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    self.filteredRecords.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)


    self.filteredRecords = self.records.filter() {
        ($0.album.lowercaseString).containsString(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If you want to search for both `album` and `artist` then replace this line:

```
($0.album.lowercaseString).containsString(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)
```

with this line:

```
($0.album.lowercaseString).containsString(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString) || ($0.artist.lowercaseString).containsString(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)
```

Comment: I tried that previously and when I did, I get this error: `Value of type '[Record]' has no member 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate'`

Comment: So what do I do than to filter the records?

Comment: this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920600/predicate-to-filter-array-of-strings-in-swift-throws-error-saying-nscfstring-is and this is another option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382580/filteredarrayusingpredicate-does-not-exist-in-swift-array

Comment: Should it not be `let array = (self.records as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)`  from the code `self.records` is an `[Record]` so you shouldn't need to cast it, however you do need to cast to an `NSArray`

Comment: Which it does throw an error which is why I started modifying the tutorial.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471012/problems-with-casting-a-swift-array-of-structs-to-an-nsarray-and-vice-versa-to-u

Comment: So then how was this code valid when he ran it? The tutorial says its Xcode 7 which should be swift 2 correct?

Comment: Yes because type of his `appleProducts` array is `[String]` but you are using struct array

Comment: I'll have to try that shortly. How could I get it to search via the artist and album?